# Is there a way to get a top of something that happened at a particular time

Tags: system-information, load-average

Is there a way for someone to take a look at system activity, like load averages and system processes that happened at an earlier time of the day? I mean is there a command for that? Say for example, I wanted to assess load averages on a machine at 9AM in the morning on the same day. How would I go about doing that? Thank you in advance UNIX/Linux community.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You need to have set it up beforehand, but if you use the `sar` command with the `sysstat` package/facility, you can look back at the past month's daily data.

Comment: That sounds really neat John, could you kindly give an example :) Thanks!

Comment: See the man page: `man sar`

Comment: I guess I have to install the sar package lol. I am not able to find it, tried a "sudo apt-cache search sar" and a plethora of results showed up.

Comment: As John said, it's in the `sysstat` package.  You may also want to look at the `acct` package - "The GNU Accounting utilities for process and login accounting"